# How to create dropdown list values depending on previous input?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need some help on rails forms. I currently have:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :student_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:student_id, Student.active.order('first_name'), :id, :proper_name, :prompt => true) %>
</div>
<br />
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :section_id %>
  <%= f.select(:section_id, get_section_list, :prompt => "Select Section") %>
</div>
```

So the first drop down is to select a student. The second drop down list is to select a section. However, right now I am displaying all sections. But I want to only the select those sections that the student is eligible for. So how do I get the input of the first drop down list in order to change the second drop down list options. If they try to choose the section without selecting a student, it should show all the options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put the select box in a partial and re-render the partial when the first select box changes.

http://keithschacht.com/getting-ajax-to-work-in-rails-3-with-jquery/